Postfix Configuration: How to Save Outgoing Emails Locally Instead of Forwarding?
I'm facing an issue with my Postfix setup where it should be saving all emails locally using a custom script, but instead, it attempts to forward outgoing emails, leading to "Relay access denied" errors. Incoming emails are processed and saved correctly.
Setup Details:

Postfix is configured to use a custom transport called saveemail for saving emails.
The system processes incoming emails correctly and triggers the saveemail script.
For outgoing emails, instead of saving, Postfix attempts to forward them, which is not the desired behavior.

Relevant Configuration:
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost

Postfix Logs:
May 13 13:42:16 mail-archive postfix/smtpd[74224]: connect from esg-app03-op1.aba.com[172.25.46.67]
May 13 13:42:16 mail-archive postfix/smtpd[74224]: D64378899D7: client=esg-app03-op1.aba.com[172.25.46.67]
May 13 13:42:16 mail-archive postfix/qmgr[66092]: D64378899D7: from=<olivia@gmail.com>, size=28112, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 13 13:42:16 mail-archive postfix/local[82557]: D64378899D7: to=<saveemail@mail-archive.aba.com>, orig_to=<jonh@abashop.com>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.03/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: /usr/local/bin/save_email.sh)
May 13 13:42:16 mail-archive postfix/qmgr[66092]: D64378899D7: removed
May 13 13:42:19 mail-archive postfix/smtpd[74251]: connect from esg-app04-op2.aba.com[172.20.42.68]
May 13 13:42:19 mail-archive postfix/smtpd[74251]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from esg-app04-op2.aba.com[172.20.42.68]: 454 4.7.1 <Kevin@mail.ru>: Relay access denied; from=<prvs=8564ac3db=Eric@abashop.com> to=<Kevin@mail.ru> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail04.abashop.com>
May 13 13:42:21 mail-archive postfix/smtpd[74224]: disconnect from esg-app03-op1.aba.com[172.25.46.67]

I'm looking for guidance on how to adjust the Postfix configuration so that it saves outgoing emails locally, just like it does with incoming ones. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
[root@mail-archive ~]# postconf -n  
command_directory = /usr/sbin  
config_directory = /etc/postfix  
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix  
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix  
debug_peer_level = 3  
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd   $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5  
default_transport = saveemail  
html_directory = no  
inet_interfaces = all  
inet_protocols = ipv4  
local_recipient_maps =  
mail_owner = postfix  
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix  
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man  
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost  
mydomain = abashop.com  
myhostname = mail-archive.aba.com  
mynetworks = 172.20.20.86/32, 127.0.0.0/8  
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix  
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix  
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES  
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples  
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix  
setgid_group = postdrop  
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550  
virtual_alias_domains = abashop.com  
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual  

[root@mail-archive ~]# postconf -M  
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd  
smtpd      pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd  
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o   syslog_name=postfix/submission -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=no -o   smtpd_tls_security_level=may -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=no -o   milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING  
smtps      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o   syslog_name=postfix/smtps -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING  
pickup     unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup  
cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup  
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr  
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr  
rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite  
bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce  
defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce  
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce  
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify  
flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush  
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap  
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap  
smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp  
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp  
showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq  
error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error  
retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error  
discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard  
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local  
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual  
lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp  
anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil  
scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache  
saveemail  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu   user=postfix argv=/usr/local/bin/save_email.sh ${sender} ${size}   ${recipient}


Relevant configuration should include the full output of postconf -M and postconf -n (as in the tag description). You may obfuscate your public names and IPs, but don't change anything else.

Added postconf -M and postconf -n

Please format code and log messages by using the {} button in the editor. This will make the post more readable.

Ok, after formatting I was finally able to read logs properly. Where do you see it relays mail instead of saving? It is clearly seen in lines 1-2-3 that it delivers to command and removes from the queue. Log lines 4-5 are about some other message, probably, it was DSN requested by the sender.

edited postfix logs

Still don't see where it doesn't save "outgoing" mails. May 13 13:42:19 mail-archive postfix/smtpd[74251]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from esg-app04-op2.aba.com[172.20.42.68]: 454 4.7.1 <Kevin@mail.ru>: Relay access denied; from=<prvs=8564ac3db=Eric@abashop.com> to=<Kevin@mail.ru> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail04.abashop.com> was rejected strictly because of relay restrictions (it did not authenticate and the IP is not in mynetworks list).

Hm... On my cellphone now, so I it is a bit combersome to read the postfix configuration on my server. In case nobody answers, I might have an answer 12 hours from now, when I have time to login to my server again. :-)

Hello @NikitaKipriyanov Thank you for answer. I just need to save all my mails in server locally. I don't need to relay it.

I added 172.20.42.68/32 to my mynetworks list and added -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks. After that I ran mailq command
E5276812F6E*  607078 Tue May 14 16:23:59  prvs=8576562fb=John@abashop.com
                                         gaben@gmail.com```

"To save mails locally" does mean "to relay" to a command (defined in the transport). Postfix does always relay (during normal operation), because this is what MTA is supposed to do. You did not have to add anything into smtpd_recipient_restrictions in this case, and you did a bad thing (made an open relay), because it's supposed to be in relay restrictions and it's already there (the default). Postfix smtpd access readme explicitly designates smtpd_recipient_restrictions for spam blocking policy, not for the relay policy.
